# Использование вебсокетов

Tags: javascript, websocket

Может кто-нибудь показать на конкретном примере, как использовать вебсокеты для выгрузки данных из БД и добавления этих данных в HTML структуру на сайте? Получилось реализовать с помощью ajax'a, но получается слишком большое количество запросов, а найти что-то дельное в интернете не удалось. В качестве бэкенда используется PHP. Если подробнее, то в БД есть записи, которые нужно добавлять в стуктуру на сайте(table), по мере  поступления этих записей в БД

Comment: что вы используете на бэкенде?

Comment: @mix в качестве бэкенда использую PHP

Comment: тогда обновите вопрос, пожалуйста, и опишите детально задачу с ЯП, чтобы вам смогли помочь.

Comment: @mix вроде более детально описал

Comment: Может кто-нибудь помочь?

Comment: при добавлении данных в БД, соединяйтесь в websocket сервером и кидайте сообщение о появлении новой записи. Чтобы было о чём с вами говорить, добавьте ваш код

Comment: Тоже интерсуюсь этой темой. Удалось ли найти решение, или дайте ссылку на похожую тему с ответом и решением.

Comment: @user418400, если вы заинтересованы в ответе на данный вопрос, то [зарабойтайте репутацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) и объявите [конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) на этот вопрос.