# Пример использования вебсокетов

Tags: php, websocket

Может кто-нибудь показать на конкретном примере, как использовать вебсокеты для выгрузки данных из БД и добавления этих данных в HTML структуру на сайте? Получилось реализовать с помощью ajax'a, но получается слишком большое количество запросов, а найти что-то дельное в интернете не удалось. В качестве бэкенда используется PHP. Если подробнее, то в БД есть записи, которые нужно добавлять в структуру на сайте(table), по мере поступления этих записей в БД

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Использование вебсокетов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882347/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2). Не нужно создавать вопрос заново, если вам никто не ответил

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он уже был задан ТС.